# Double comparatives

Tags: grammar, comparative-constructions, comparison, comparative, comparative-degree

As I know, "spend" has different structures:
Spend time V-ing/ Spend time on sth
She spends a lot of time working. She feels stressed.
If I use Double comparatives, this sentence will be :
The more time she spends on work, the more stressed she feels.
I wonder my answer is correct or incorrect ?

Comment: This is just a duplicate of  [Using Double comparatives](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/335000/using-double-comparatives) asked 6 hours earlier. At least the original has some formatting; this is just a plaintext copy/paste.

Answer (score 1):

It's entirely correct and sounds fine, although I'd prefer 'The more she works' to 'The more time she spends on work'.

You could also go with 'the more she works, the greater her stress'.

Comment: thanks a lot for your reply.